# magic number in compiled format of tic

Tags: ncurses, terminfo

I am reading about the terminfo file format and the format of tic compiled files. I found the documentation of this format, but in this documentation they write about the first two bytes in the file as 1A 01 in order of precedence. To check, I opened the compiled format of my terminal emulator and others, but they contain bytes 1E 02 in order of precedence. What's it?

hexdump(first 8 bytes) of /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color:
`0000000   1E 02 30 00  1C 00 0F 00`

Documentation: https://linux.die.net/man/5/term

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a very old copy of the manual page (at least 5 years: the linked [terminfo](https://linux.die.net/man/5/terminfo) manual page says **`20090207`**).  If you use the **`file`** program (assuming a reasonably up-to-date system), you'll see the answer.

Here's the expected output for that case:

```
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm+256color:     Compiled 32-bit terminfo entry "xterm+256color"
```

and for the manual's example

```
/usr/share/terminfo/a/adm3a: Compiled terminfo entry "adm3a"
```

The difference came in with [ncurses 6.1](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.1.html) in January 2018, along with updates for [term(5)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html).  The section [*Extended Number Format*](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/term.5.html#h3-EXTENDED-NUMBER-FORMAT) explains that a different *magic* number was needed to provide for 32-bit numbers versus the older 16-bit numbers.